# SQL for each column in Deleted and Inserted

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am creating a trigger and I want to parse all columns of Deleted and Inserted when I edit a row. So if col1 of Deleted is different than col1 of Inserted then store this change in another table. Here is how I have achieved this but I want to make it dynamic.

```
    if not exists (select * from deleted d join inserted i on d.Cisitid = i.Cisitid ) and @Action in ('U') -- UpdateCisitid
BEGIN
    select  @audit_oldvalue = Cisitid from deleted;
    select @audit_value = Cisitid from inserted;

    insert into [dbo].[AuditTrailCTables]([TSid],[TableName],[TSField],[OldValue],[NewValue],[changedate],[Change_Action],[Change_user],[Columns_Updated])
    select Cisitid,@tablename,'Cisitid', @audit_oldvalue, @audit_value,getdate(),@Action, coalesce(ModifiedBy,suser_name()), 'Cisitid'
    from inserted 

    --Cformid

    select  @audit_oldvalue = Cformid from deleted;
    select @audit_value = Cformid from inserted;

    insert into [dbo].[AuditTrailCTables]([TSid],[TableName],[TSField],[OldValue],[NewValue],[changedate],[Change_Action],[Change_user],[Columns_Updated])
    select Cisitid,@tablename,'Cformid', @audit_oldvalue, @audit_value,getdate(),@Action, coalesce(ModifiedBy,suser_name()), 'Cformid'
    from inserted 

    --CreatedDate

    select  @audit_oldvalue = CreatedDate from deleted;
    select @audit_value = CreatedDate from inserted;

    insert into [dbo].[AuditTrailCTables]([TSid],[TableName],[TSField],[OldValue],[NewValue],[changedate],[Change_Action],[Change_user],[Columns_Updated])
    select Cisitid,@tablename,'CreatedDate', @audit_oldvalue, @audit_value,getdate(),@Action, coalesce(ModifiedBy,suser_name()), 'CreatedDate'
    from inserted 

    --CreatedBy

    select  @audit_oldvalue = CreatedBy from deleted;
    select @audit_value = CreatedBy from inserted;

    insert into [dbo].[AuditTrailCTables]([TSid],[TableName],[TSField],[OldValue],[NewValue],[changedate],[Change_Action],[Change_user],[Columns_Updated])
    select Cisitid,@tablename,'CreatedBy', @audit_oldvalue, @audit_value,getdate(),@Action, coalesce(ModifiedBy,suser_name()), 'CreatedBy'
    from inserted 
END
```

Comment: Word of warning: a trigger should be **very small and nimble** and it should do the **minimal amount of work possible** .... do **not** put large calculations, extensive data manipuliation etc. into a trigger. This is a recipe for disaster. The trigger is being executed *in the context and transaction* of the statement that caused this trigger to fire - and that statement will be blocked until the trigger is done. Try to **scale down** the amount of work your trigger is doing!

Comment: Have you tried [CDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server)?

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR fundamental flaw. It assumes there will only ever be a single row in the inserted and delete tables. In sql server triggers fire once per operation, as such triggers need to be set based. This will fail miserably with an insert or update that affects even 2 rows.

Comment: Create a DDL trigger on table that drops and dynamically recreates the DML trigger on the same table, using the current set of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try using UPDATE function:

```
IF UPDATE(Cisitid)
    insert into [dbo].[AuditTrailCTables]([TSid],[TableName],[TSField],[OldValue],
    [NewValue],[changedate],[Change_Action],[Change_user],[Columns_Updated])
         select Cisitid,@tablename,'Cisitid', @audit_oldvalue, 
    @audit_value,getdate(),@Action, coalesce(ModifiedBy,suser_name()), 'Cisitid'
    from inserted 

etc..
```

Comment: But this solution doesnt make it dynamic.. For example if I change a column name or add a new column its not going to work. Thats why I am looking something like for each row in deleted etc...

Comment: @alxem As I said in the comments above, dynamically recreate the trigger (using multiple IF UPDATE statements) on DDL changes.